# Give an example of two function f and g such that f doesn't belong to O(g) and g doesn't belong to O(f).

Tags: algorithms

Give an example of two function f and g such that f doesn't belong to O(g) and g doesn't belong to O(f).

I'm thinking something with asymptotes, but I can't seem to make it work out.

Answer (score 4):

For example, $f(x) = x \sin x$ and $g(x) = 1$.